Unable to connect to certain servers
I've been having a recurring problem where I'm unable to connect to certain servers. For example: I'm able to make Google searches, but unable to visit any of the links. Or I'm able to play a game, but when I log out I'm unable to log back in. I believe this is an issue with Windows Firewall, because turning it off & back on again seems to fix the issue. Leaving my Firewall off doesn't seem to fix it though. I'm using Windows 11, although this problem has persisted with Windows 10 as well. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this issue?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A common cause for failure to reach a site is because DNS lookup fails.
As an experiment, try changing DNS resolution. For example,

If DNS resolution is set to automatic, try Cloudflare or Google, or
If it's set to a specific DNS server, try getting it automatically..



Open the Network and Sharing Center control panel.
Click on a connection, e.g., Ethernet or a WiFi server.
In the status dialog, select Properties.
In the Properties dialog, select Internet Protocol Version 4, then click the Properties button.
Set the DNS server IP address, as supplied by Cloudflare, Google or elesewhere, or select Obtain DNS server address automatically.

This setting may need to be changed for different service providers. For example, a hotel or library might require you to use automatic lookup, but at home, your ISP might allow you to set the DNS server.

I tried this, and unfortunately my problem still persists. Thanks for the help though!
